# Is there a standard to specify a binary format in json

Tags: json, binary, protocol-buffers, binary-data

I would like to know whether there is some standard that specifies binary formats using JSON as the describing language, similar to google's protocol buffers.

Protocol buffers seem very powerful but they require parsing of yet another language and considerable overhead, especially for compiled languages such as C++.

So I am wondering whether there is some accepted standard that uses JSON to describe a binary format. (Parsing the binary data might then still require some manual steps, but at least a clear and unique description of the data can be made available.)

To be clear, I am not talking about encoding binary data in JSON, I am talking about describing binary data in JSON.

Comment: "_considerable overhead, especially for compiled languages_". What kind of overhead? PB parser creates source code reflection of the current PB description. You don't have to run PB parser with every compilation of your project. How would JSON description improve it? You would have to parse it anyway.

Comment: With overhead I also mean 'overhead for the programmer'. Indeed, it would require no runtime parsing which is a big pro. I am actually quite impressed with the protocol buffers. However I am also looking for something that is a bit more lightweight because our binary data is fairly limited in complexity and because our programmers are a bit conservative so I doubt whether protocol buffers will get a warm welcome.

Comment: Alright that makes sense. You should have explained the overhead right away. Asking good questions on SO takes practice :)

Answer (score 0):

Head to the ultimate [Wikipedia listing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats) and evaluate for yourself. I don't know what is the right argument to overcome your programmer's inertia. I'd consider Apache Avro the most fitting your requirement - it has JSON description.

For least friction, you could try MessagePack or BSON, which **are** JSON themselves, just better packed. But, by not having external declaration, need to be self descriptive, so must transport the field names on wire - so it's not as "binary" and compact as Protocol Buffers or Avro.